# How to implement a CORS Filter in play 2.2.0 Java?

Tags: java, playframework, cors

I was looking everywhere, but all the solutions that I founded didn't work for me, and I think that's the problem is in my version of play, but anyway, someone can help me to implement a CORS filter Java in a play 2.2.0+. Sorry about my English, I'm not so sure if it's clear.

I implemented this code:

```
public class CorsComposition {

    /**
     * Wraps the annotated action in an <code>CorsAction</code>.
     */
    @With(CorsAction.class)
    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Cors {
        String value() default "*";
    }

    public static class CorsAction extends Action<Cors> {

        @Override
        public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context context) throws Throwable {
            Response response = context.response();
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            //Handle preflight requests
            if(context.request().method().equals("POST")) {
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

                return delegate.call(context);
            }

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
            return delegate.call(context);
        }


    }
}
```

And in my controllers, I put the annotation @Cors. That's ok for requests but when I use POST, it doesn't work. The error of CROSS ORIGIN NOT ALLOWED is showing on my Chrome console.

Comment: Please show us what you did so far. StackOverflow can not give you finished implementations without some help by you. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: Sorry, the question was editaded

Comment: The problem was solved, in really, the problem was the return of method that is not returned because a Binding error stop the method. So this code works for CORS problem, so anyone can use it.

Comment: Place an answer for your own question and mark it as correct one after two days instead placing SOLVED in the question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, in really, the problem was the return of method that is not returned because a Binding error stop the method. So this code works for CORS problem, so anyone can use it.

Comment: could you please explain how the Route OPTIONs /cors Controller.cors() would work. Are you suggesting that CorsComposition should extend controller. Even if it does Cors is not a recognizable function

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to java and play. thx a lot for this code @renatomattos2912!

i just had some problems with the correct includes. so i hope that it is okay, when i post the final file version:

```
path: app/actions/CorsComposition.java
```

file:

```
package actions;

import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.SimpleResult;
import play.mvc.With;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public class CorsComposition {

    /**
     * Wraps the annotated action in an <code>CorsAction</code>.
     */
    @With(CorsAction.class)
    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Cors {
        String value() default "*";
    }

    public static class CorsAction extends Action<Cors> {

        @Override
        public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
            Http.Response response = context.response();
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            //Handle preflight requests
            if(context.request().method().equals("POST")) {
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

                return delegate.call(context);
            }

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
            return delegate.call(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**update**
add these to all your controllers too:

```
@CorsComposition.Cors
```

this code above worked for me for GET requests. but for posts etc, i got the same error.
to fix that too, i've added these route in my route config

```
OPTIONS        /*path                          controllers.Application.preflight(path: String)
```

and in my application Controller:

```
public static Result preflight(String path) {

    return ok("");

}
```

Comment: hi @roman, thank you and thanks this blog post for help me too http://daniel.reuterwall.com/blog/2013/04/15/play-with-cors/ and enjoy the code =). About your question, maybe this gist help you https://gist.github.com/renatomattos2912/9844710

Comment: thanks for your links @renatomattos2912! i found these before too. but they have slight different code and do not work on play 2.2.X (in my setup?)

Comment: yes, the blog code don't work on play 2.2+, but the code of my gist works, i was have the same issue that you have now, then i change the blog code and my gist is the result, if you still have problems, tell me. Cheers

Comment: What should I add in routes file.

OPTIONS /what?   what.